# IntelliJ IDEA current file tab closes on opening a different file

Tags: intellij-idea

Every time I open a new file (single click), the existing file closes by itself. It started happening in the latest version. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Project tool window, click the three vertical dots and uncheck `Enable Preview Tab` option (which is on by default)

[image]